# Getting or deleting cache entries in Flask with the key starting with (or containing) a substring

Tags: python, caching, flask, memcached, flask-cache

I'm trying to delete all entries in the cache store that contain (in this case start with) a substring of the cache key, but I don't see any easy way of doing this. I'm using Memcache as backend.

If I understand the code correctly, I need to pass the full cache key when calling `delete` or `delete_many`. Is there any other way of doing this?

I'll explain what I'm trying to do in case there is a better way: I need to clear the cache for certain users when they modify their settings. Clearing the cache with `clear()` will remove the cache entries for all the users, which are some 110K, so I don't want to use that.

I am generating `key_prefix` with the ID of the user, the request's path, and other variables. The cache keys always start with the ID of the authenticated user. So ideally I would use something like `delete_many(user_id + ".*")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported because Memcache is designed to be a distributed hash. There's no index of keys stored to search in.

Ideally you *should* know what suffixes a key may have.
If not, you could maintain an index yourself in a special key for the user.
Like `user_id + '_keys'` which contains a *list* of keys.
This way you can cycle key by key and delete all the cache for the user.

You can override the `.set` function to manage this new key.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion and I was in fact already working on an implementation very similar to what you propose here. The only "unknown" variable of the keys are the paths of the requests, so my idea is to just cycle through all the urls that allow a GET and remove all keys with user_id + url + <other_known_variables>. Although not ideal, that should work for my case.